# How to send multicast message in Silverlight Local Communication?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, messaging

Is there a way to send multicast messages in Silverlight Local Communication?
each LocalMessageReceiver requires a unique name, but I need a way to send global message to all receivers.
thanks!

Comment: Are all SL apps involved peers to each other or does one have a more master like role?  IOW can any app broadcast a message to the others or is there just one sending the "multicast messages"?

Comment: they are all peers to each other. any app should be able to broadcast a message to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way I see is by using a well-known name.

In any case, receivers have know what kind of message and data is being send so some kind of indication/identification of the message is needed anyway.